# How to setup a dualboot with Debian and FreeDOS

Tags: debian, multi-boot, grub, freedos

I am running Debian on a very old EEEPC which is ok. Unfortunately its Intel-Atom-Processor is not capable of virtualizing a second OS. So I would like to add FreeDOS to GRUB and run it natively to tinker around with it. I already created a partition for FreeDOS. But how can I install it and add it to GRUB?

Answer (score 0):

https://wiki.debian.org/DualBoot/FreeDOS should help you to get the `memdisk` loader and declare it in `grub`. You will need a floppy disk image.